How to link object data whilst keeping original rotation data
I have a model where I am trying to replace a bunch of placement planes with a screw model. I am hoping to be able to use linking object data to make this work but so far I am struggling. I have duplicated one such placement plane to demonstrate. You can see the set up below:

I have applied scale on both the plane and the screw, I have set the origin to geometry on the plane and then I have used object linking data to replace the plane with the screw. My end result is this:

As you can see the screw is not facing the direction I would like it to, I want it to be facing out of the plane (i.e. sort of towards the top right in the image). I've tried applying rotation but that only ends up with the screw being the exact orientation it is currently. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You can use instance on faces, but as I see, you have at least 2 faces, not one.

Of course applying the rotation (i.e. resetting all rotation values to 0° without changing the mesh's orientation) leads to the screw being oriented as it is originally. The problem is, you are not showing any information how this plane is oriented or how the screw is oriented (since I assume the arrows are using Global orientation, not Local), no rotation values either. Generally the Link Object Data works like this: the "new" screw will be placed with its origin where the plane's origin is, its Z axis will point in the direction where the plane's (local) Z axis points.
